# pysvn : get current logged in Username

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, pysvn

How to get current logged in Username using pysvn API.

We enabled windows authentication(Integrated) in VisualSVN server. So no need to provide username and password to login.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Since the pysvn module deals solely with svn you can't - not 100% impossible to fool, (but little is), the following will usually get you the username logged in as asked:

```
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getuser()
```